# C# Xml Node InnerText with LineBreaks - How to write and Read

Tags: c#, xml, linefeed

I want to store a memo text with line breaks in a xml node using XmlDocument object in c#.  I am able to write it with simple assignment of inner Text.

It looks like the following

```
<CSScript>
    Line 1
    ...
    ...
    Line n
</CSScript>
```

But, i am unable to read it, how to go about it ?

Comment: Can you show the code? What happens when you read from the `InnerText` property?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [`PreserveWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  Before you `.Load()` your XML data, set it to true, like so:

```
string filename = "C:\\myxml.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xmlDoc.Load(filename);
```

And similarly, before calling `.Save()`, set it to true:

```
xmlDoc.SomethingNode.InnerText = "Line 1\r\n...\r\n....";
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true; // assuming it hasn't already been set to true
xmlDoc.Save(someFileLocation);
```

Note that not all XML processors/viewers will follow this behavior - they may end up treating it (perhaps erroneously) as insignificant whitespace and stripping it, depending on how your document is structured (MSIE, for example, will likely do this if you open the document to view it in the browser, but won't actually change the text source).  Also note that if you're using LINQ to XML, you can use `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` and `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` to similar effect.